# Change Color of UIButton in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I set the title of `NavigationBar` and changed it's color which is successful using the following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.title = @"SHARE";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout =UIRectEdgeNone;
```

As you can see the bar color is BLACK and it's title color is WHITE. Now I want to add a button to ir's right. Button is added successfully but it's not changing the color.

```
UIButton *forwdButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    forwdButton.titleLabel.text = @"Send";
    [forwdButton.titleLabel setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [forwdButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
    [forwdButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIBarButtonItem *barFrwdItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:forwdButton];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barFrwdItem;
```

In this code I'm having problem in these lines:

```
forwdButton.titleLabel.text = @"Send";
        [forwdButton.titleLabel setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

It still shows a black button. It's not changing it's color.
I've tried to do the following:

```
[barFrwdItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; //Which is the UIBarButtonItem
```

and also

```
[forwdButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // which is the UIButton
```

Comment: set the bar button item tint color not the button tint color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding button in wrong way.Please add right button like this.

```
UIBarButtonItem *chkmanuaaly = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=chkmanuaaly;
```

After that add this line to change the color

```
[chkmanuaaly setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
               [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] 
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: It's working the button is now visible but it's in blur color. I've also tried `[UIBarButtonItem appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Working perfect :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to create a UIBarButtonItem and have it respond to an action, you don't necessarily need to create a sub view.

```
UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(someMethod:)];
```

From here you can either set the tint color on the UIBarButton or if you want all buttons on the UINavigationController to be set to the same color you can set the tint color on the navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

or

```
[forwardButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor];
```